# Remove *args and **kwargs from method signatures using rope

Tags: python, refactoring, signature, variadic-functions, rope

I'm using eric4 and its rope plug-in to refactor some code.
I have many method whose signatures use the `*args` and `**kwargs` syntax.
I'd like to change these signatures an remove this parameters.

I've tried using the `Refactoring>Refactoring>Change Method Signature` but this does not remove `*args` and `**kwargs` parameters.

I wonder if this is a limitation of rope itself, or if it's eric's plug-in that does not support this feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you want to remove `*args` and `**kwargs`? To refactor those functions, a refactoring library would need to perform quite a bit of introspection to know the correct parameters.

For example, how would you refactor the following function:

```
def f(*args, **kwargs):
    a = args[0]
    b = args[1]
    c = kwargs.get('c', 3)
    d = kwargs.get('d', 4)
    print a, b, c, d
```

You could turn it into:

```
def f(a, b, c=3, d=4):
    print a, b, c, d
```

It requires quite a bit of code analysis to do this already and for real functions it is even harder. The number of positional and keyword arguments can vary (e.g., the function could iterate over `args`) which makes it difficult to determine the correct function arguments.

Unless there is a real need, I would keep the `*args` and `**kwargs` and focus on other refactoring efforts.

Comment: and there is worse, the arguments could be passed off to another function as well, so the analysis to know what's in could have to reach very deep in the call tree.

Comment: Okay, so it's rope's limitation.anyway my `*args` and `**kwargs` are, at the moment, not even used. They were put here because these methods are part of a semi-abstract class which implements some logic, but does not implement the concrete steps, so I've put them to allow subclasses to pass options around. Now I've understand there are other, much cleaner ways, of doing this (such as passing options to the constructor of the class) and so I'd like to remove them. Nevermind, I'll remove them by hand.
Anyway, thank you for your explanation